# Laravel9 how to disable specific date if exist in record 10 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

if it exist 10 times in db that date will be disable

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control input-md" min="{{$todayDate}}" name="date"
                        @if(App\Models\Reservation::where('date', $value->date)
                                ->where('time')
                                    disabled  
                                        
                                @endif  
                        value="{{old('date')}}" required readonly/>
```

Script:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  minDate: new Date(), 
  maxDate: '+30d'

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```php
App\Models\Reservation::where('date', $value->date)->count() > 10
```

Using `count` it is literally counting how many rows it returns. Using `exists` only checks if the query returns something (hence data exists).